# mysql - how to check and rollback mySql queries

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, transactions

I have a question about mySql queries which i use PHP to make -

In my code i insert data to table - main_query . if the insert part want well i do second insert query - sub_query.

How do i cancel the first insert query if the second was failed? I mean - is it possible to send both queries to be checked before i actually execute them? or - is it possible to do rollback for the first "main_query" query?

```
$main_query = "INSERT INTO table_1 (...) VALUES (...)";
$res = $conn->query($main_query);

if ($res)
{
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    
    $sub_query = "INSERT INTO table_2 (...) VALUES (...)"; // use var "id" here
    $res = $conn->query($sub_query);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you need to use [transactions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) and [rollback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.rollback.php):

```
# start mysql transaction
mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

$main_query = "INSERT INTO table_1 (...) VALUES (...)";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $main_query);

if ($res)
{
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
    
    $sub_query = "INSERT INTO table_2 (...) VALUES (...)"; // use var "id" here
    $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sub_query);
    if ($res) {
        # both inserts succeed - do commit
        mysqli_commit($conn);
    }
    else {
        # second insert fail - do rollback
        mysqli_rollback($conn); 
    }
} else  {
    # first insert fail - do rollback
    mysqli_rollback($conn); 
}
```

or we can use object oriented style like:

```
# start mysql transaction
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

$main_query = "INSERT INTO table_1 (...) VALUES (...)";
$res = $mysqli->query($main_query);

if ($res)
{
    $id = $mysqli->insert_id;

    $sub_query = "INSERT INTO table_2 (...) VALUES (...)"; // use var "id" here
    $res = $mysqli->query($sub_query);
    if ($res) {
        # both inserts succeed - do commit
        $mysqli->commit();
    }
    else {
        # second insert fail - do rollback
        $mysqli->rollback(); 
    }
} else  {
    # first insert fail - do rollback
    $mysqli->rollback(); 
}
```

Look working example here [PHPize.online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=57ea5bfbe19e4ec2f3f794dd1836a937&sqlses=94465bffe04ea434c2e1d32e2b79b6cf)

Comment: Hi Slava - did you meant `$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);` ?

Comment: Also - what is `$link` ? is it my `$conn` ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. $link in same $conn.  You can Object oriented style `$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY);` or functional style `mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY)`  as well

Comment: Ok, but in your example, will i be able to get back the $id value? `$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` and use it for the second query?

Comment: I'm getting the follow error: `Cannot execute statement in a READ ONLY transaction`. are you sure about `MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_ONLY` ?

Comment: Try it in read/write mode `mysqli_begin_transaction($conn, MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);`